# Parse Swift Documentation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I see that there are swift code examples in the [iOS guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide), however, when I'm looking in the [official documentation](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/), I cannot find a Swift version (i.e. method signatures are given in obj-c). Where is it located? or is it simply not available yet?

P.S. I use dash (by kapeli) it would be great to have such added to their docset as well.

Comment: The class reference is in Objective-C (but as Daij-Djan says, the Swift interface is the same), but [all the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS) is in both Objective-C and Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take objC and apply it 1:1  to swift  ... only the syntax of the language changed -- EVERYTHING is identical (types, concepts) -- if you use those frameworks like parse or uikit or Facebook or whatever. **they didn't miraculously change :)**

Comment: Thanks! i'm thinking the same. however, i see that some of the method signatures seem to be different. For instance: `- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)block` vs. `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
      (objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)`.

Comment: no they equal. blocks are closures. a PFArrayResultBlock block for example DOES provide objects and error.

Comment: as rob said there even is objc and swift documentation :) -- for the above https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS (search for findObjectsIn :))